# Is there a 2D character animation SDK for creating moving personas like in PocketGems’ “Episode” app?

Tags: animation, sdk

“Episode” by PocketGems has expressive 2D Avatars that move their limbs and faces in realistic ways. Is there an SDK in any language that attempts the same sort of permutations?

For example see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDl1nvrp5Ys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [skeletal animations via SceneKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnskinner).

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//$SITEURL$/help/deleted-answers)